# ECS task cannot access resources in public internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have the following setup:

- ECS cluster with underlying EC2 instances
- Internet gateway attached to my vpc
- Route table association between my igw and public subnets

Currently I have an API gateway in front of my API, and I use Service discovery to route traffic to my containers in ECS.

In continuation, my cluster is in a public subnet, the primary reasons being that I'm trying to save cost as much as possible, i.e. ditching a NAT.

For my underlying ec2 instances in ecs, A public ip is associated and the security groups only allow ingress from api gateway, but **allows all eagress traffic**.

My initial thought was, that it would be enough for my container instances to access public endpoints, i.e. stripe api and cognito-idp, but for some reason my container instances do not have public internet access.

The configuration on my task is as follows:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "aws-ecs-api-task" {
  family = "myservice-api-task"

  container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
  [
    {
      "name": "${local.api_container_name}",
      "image": "${aws_ecr_repository.aws-ecr-api.repository_url}:latest",
      "cpu": ${var.api_container_cpu},
      "memory": ${var.api_container_memory},
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": ${var.api_container_port},
          "hostPort": ${var.api_container_host_port}
        }
      ],
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.api-log-group.id}",
          "awslogs-region": "${var.region}",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "${var.app_name}-${var.environment}"
        }
      },
      "healthcheck": {
        "command": ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:${var.api_container_port}/api/1.0/general/version || exit 1"]
      },
      "essential": true,
      "networkMode": "awsvpc"
    }
  ]
  DEFINITION

  requires_compatibilities = ["EC2"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  memory                   = var.api_container_memory
  cpu                      = var.api_container_cpu
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionRole.arn
  task_role_arn            = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_role.arn

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.app_name}-ecs-api-task-definition"
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}
```

And service:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "aws-ecs-service_api" {
  name                               = "ecs_service-api-${var.environment}"
  cluster                            = var.ecs_cluster_id
  task_definition                    = aws_ecs_task_definition.aws-ecs-api-task.arn
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 200 #during red/green it is allowed to spawn 200% of desired tasks
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 100 #always have one healthy pod
  desired_count                      = var.api_container_desired_count
  scheduling_strategy                = "REPLICA"
  force_new_deployment               = false

  capacity_provider_strategy {
    capacity_provider = var.capacity_provider_name
    weight            = 100
    base              = 1
  }

  network_configuration {
    subnets          = var.ecs_service_subnet_ids
    assign_public_ip = false
    security_groups  = [aws_security_group.ecs_service_api_sg.id]
  }

  service_registries {
    registry_arn   = aws_service_discovery_service.ecs-discovery-service.arn
    port           = var.api_container_port
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.app_name}-ecs_service-api"
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}
```

I tried changing the network type to host, but it did not have an effect. Also I am not super knowledgeable about the different network configurations.

I hope you guys may be able to help me out with this issue - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `awsvpc` network mode. This means that each ECS task gets its own Elastic Network Interface (ENI). With this configuration, the ECS tasks do not use the underlying EC2 instance's network connection, they have their own network connection, with their own IP addresses.

You are currently disabling public IP assignment to your ECS tasks in the ECS service `network_configuration` block. You will need to change `assign_public_ip` to `true` in order to have ECS assign public IP addresses to the ECS Task's ENIs, so that the ECS tasks can access resources outside of the VPC.

---

> "In continuation, my cluster is in a public subnet, the primary reasons being that I'm trying to save cost as much as possible, i.e. ditching a NAT."

Please note that in [the near future](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-public-ipv4-address-charge-public-ip-insights/), AWS is going to start charging for each public IP you have in your account, and you are sort-of doubling up on public IPs by assigning them to EC2 instances, and then using `awsvpc` network mode which also requires them (as explained above). You may want to calculate how much this is going to cost you, versus a NAT Gateway.

Comment: I didn't know that AWS start charging for IPs, anyway, seems like I cannot assign public ips to ec2 launch type. 

What might my options be then?

Comment: I forgot you can't use public IP with `awsvpc` ECS deployed to EC2. You can only do that with Fargate deployments. So your options are to use a different network mode, so you can use the EC2 instance's public IP from your ECS task: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/networking-networkmode.html or switch to private subnets and a NAT Gateway.

Comment: I ended up putting everything in a private subnet with a nat in a public subnet, works flawless.. but it is an expensive solution.